# what does the term calculated promises means?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage

It was said in a song called "all stars are closer" 
so I wanna know what does it mean exactly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvOh7vVqlaE

Comment: Sometimes *calculated* is used in a context that means there is an ulterior motive. I haven't watched your video yet.

Comment: Hi Omar, and welcome to EL&U. As the site aims to be a permanent repository, links should be accompanied by an appropriate extract. In the case of a video, it's even more important to provide a transcript of the relevant portion. As it stands, there isn't enough context directly in your question to answer it definitively.

Answer (score 1):

> I recognize your false confidence and **calculated promises** all in your
>   conversation

As noted by @jxh, *calculated* can often carry a negative connotation of a shrewd (bordering on inhuman) premeditation. As such, the phrase *calculated promises* would connote a sort of manipulation that the author feels is receiving from this person.